# Java Web Start hangs when constructing a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, java-web-start

I need help when starting my program with Java Web Start.

I start my program from the homepage the program just hangs with a javaw-process in the process handler. When I dump the threads, using jvisualvm, I see that it hung in the "AWT-EventQueue-0" thread (when constructing my JFrame):

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x02da7c00 nid=0x1414 runnable [0x0367f000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getScreenInsets(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getScreenInsets(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at se.testing.Application$2.run(Application.java:170)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
```

Here is what the main looks like:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    ....

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**: And here is the jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="6.0+" 
      codebase="http://localhost/archive/Application-1.0.0/"
      href="application.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Application</title>
    <vendor>Testing</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://localhost/" />
    <description></description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="timeout" policy="always" />
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="Application-1.0.0.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="Framework-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="WebServices-1.0.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="axis-1.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
    <jar href="spring-2.5.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-net-2.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="nanoxml-2.2.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="jtds-1.2.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-discovery-0.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="se.testing.Application">
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

**What could be wrong?!**
(It is the first place I touch the GUI and I'm on Windows XP.)

Also, I noticed that I have another AWT thread (??!?!) also hanging at different places:

From run 1 I got it to hang here:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x03448800 nid=0x152c runnable [0x036cf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.nativeHandleEvent(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And from run 2:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-1" prio=6 tid=0x03448800 nid=0x1638 runnable [0x036cf000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.isWindowTranslucencySupported(Native Method)
        at com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.isWindowTranslucencySupported(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.isTranslucencySupported(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.updateWindows(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If someone finds another solution I accept it directly!** I'm not contempt with the current solution...

---

It seems that it only happens when using Intel HD Graphics (my system is Core i3 clarkdale).

Possible solutions are (tested!):

- Using windows default drivers (~vga drivers)
- New graphic card

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: Are you able to run the jar locally with no issues? If yes then maybe post the jnlp file.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly seems like some kind of problem with the graphics drivers and java.

See if [this link to Java 2D system settings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html) helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried constructing the GUI in the main thread? The event handling thread if for - handling events :-)

Comment: Hum, I'm pretty sure that you should not even construct the gui in another thread, but I'll try! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setVisible( true );
}
```

Comment: Tried it, did not work. It just hung in "javawsApplicationMain" instead.